# Pen tool moving and anchor moving

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am trying to learn more about the pen tool in photoshop. I understand its basic usage for paths/selection/shapes. The thing that I dont understand is the following:
When i start to draw path, i complete it in several points, then if I hold ctr and press on the path I move the entire selection. Later if I deselect and select it again and try to move it with CTR and mouse it moves a specific point, not the entire selection?

Comment: The cursor matters... Black pointer cursor = entire path, white (hollow) pointer cursor = points.